# C# Cookie not being set on browser

Tags: c#, .net, cookies

I am trying to set a cookie for domain `b.com`, but the page which is setting the cookie is on `a.com`

the code is as below

```
HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("UserSettings");
myCookie["Font"] = "Arial";
myCookie["Color"] = "Blue";
myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
myCookie.domain = "b.com";
myCookie.path ="/";
Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
```

I'm pretty sure this part of the code is working as I am able to do a `request.cookies` to get the values. However, it is not really set on my browser. When I open a browser (such as Chrome and Firefox) and view all the cookies, then search for domain `"b.com`", nothing is found! Is the cookie is not really set? I tried all night to figure this out but I can't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That sounds like it shouldn't work. I don't think you can change cookies on domains other than your own... It seems like a security risk to me.

Comment: anyway for me to set for other domain, i also doubt this is the problem, but i hope there is a way to solve. i am not thinking to hack other site, but need to do something on my company intranet sites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342140/cross-domain-cookies), there is no way to create a cookie for a different domain. If it's possible for you, you could work your way with redirections from domain to domain to set the cookies.